# SAS mainframe replace 20..99 to 200099

Tags: sas

In my the sas mainframe code how to replace . with 0?

```
data newlic;
INPUT @1 LICNO $10.;       
DATALINES;                 
203....412                 
...3300421                 
9955..032.                 
;                          
RUN;                       
PROC PRINT DATA = NEWLIC;  
RUN;                       
DATA MYDATA;               
SET NEWLIC;                
  ARRAY A(*) _NUMERIC_;      
  DO I=1 TO DIM(A);          
  IF A(I) = . THEN A(I) = 0; 
 END;                       
DROP I;                    
 RUN;                       
PROC PRINT DATA = MYDATA;  
RUN;
```

my required output

```
2030000412                 
0003300421                 
9955000320
```

the requirement is to replace '.' to 0

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to replace all non-alphanumeric characters with a 0:

`s/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/0/`

You can implement regex replacements in SAS with `prxchange()`.

```
data mydata;
    set newlic;

    licno = prxchange('s/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/0/', -1, licno);
run;
```

Comment: Hi Stu Sztukowski,

Comment: Thanks for the quick response the code give by you has working fine but my main reqment is to any non numeric like space/junk/charterer those want to replace with 0

Comment: Now the requirement is  , if licence not numeric  do not abend   instead substitute the value with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TRANSLATE() function to replace unwanted characters with '0'.  You can use the COMPRESS() function with `d` modifier to find any non-digit characters that exist in the value.

```
fixed=translate(licno,repeat('0',255),compress(licno,,'d'));
```

Results:

```
Obs    LICNO           fixed

 1     1234567890    1234567890
 2     ABC      9    0000000009
 3     203....412    2030000412
 4     ...3300421    0003300421
 5     9955..032.    9955000320
 6     123           1230000000
```

Comment: Hi Tom,
Thanks for the quick response you code is exlent but i am getting one error 
15         FIXED=TRANSLATE(LICNO,REPEAT('0',255),COMPRESS(LICNO,,'D'));
ERROR: Null parameters for COMPRESS are invalid.

Comment: kindly share some solution for the above issue

Comment: kindly give some solution for the above issue 
thanks & Regards 
krishna

Comment: Are you trying to use it in SQL code?  You can just type out the digits.  `COMPRESS(LICNO,'0123456789')`

Comment: Thanks & Regards
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression pattern metacharacter `\D` to locate non-digit characters and replace them with `0` in a use of `PRXCHANGE()`.

From the complete list in the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p0s9ilagexmjl8n1u7e1t1jfnzlk.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

> `\d`    matches a digit character that is equivalent to `[0−9]`.
> `\D`    matches any character that is not a digit.

Example:

```
data have; input
licno $char10.; datalines;
1234567890
ABC      9
203....412
...3300421
9955..032.
123       
;

data want;
  set have;
  fixed = prxchange('s/\D/0/', -1, licno);
run;
```